# How do I move an object in dwarf fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I misplaced an item (built an armorstand away from the training area) and i want to move it to the correct location. How do i do that? I can't seem to dump the item, remove etc?

Comment: A built  armourstand is not a item - once it is built it is a building.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the <kbd>q</kbd> command to view the built object and when you have it selected, press <kbd>x</kbd> to remove the construction. The dwarves will deconstruct it and put it back in the stockpile.

Then just rebuild it in the correct location.

Note that if a dwarf is performing the task of moving an item to a stockpile it will be considered "in use" (and the item will be marked with "TSK") even before the dwarf reaches and picks up the item. You won't be able to select it for rebuilding until the task is not active due to completion or cancellation. You can forbid item within before deconstruction, or you can forbid the item to cancel the hauling job. Afterwards, while paused, unforbid the item and rebuild it before the hauling task is assigned again.

Comment: OP is correct. It is indeed 'q', then arrow to the armorstand, then 'x' to remove it. Once a dorf with the appropriate hauling labor removes it, you may re-place it where you actually want it.

Comment: Also it does not have to be moved to stockpile. As soon as it is "deconsturcted" the item is reusable anywhere else.

Comment: Yes, but it will not be actually re-constructed until it has reached the stockpile. The best way for doing this is creating a specific stockpile for it near the place where you want it to be re-constructed. This way the armorstand will be translated there when deconstructed and you will lose less time.

Comment: Actually, from my understanding, it can be used from where it is, unless a dwarf is *actively about to move it*. If your dwarves are too busy doing other things, it may not have moved by the time you are ready to rebuild it in the appropriate place.

Comment: @Balen If you try and rebuild it immediately afterwards it's not available on the list. Raven might be right about the clarification though. I'll edit that in.

Comment: I don't know how i overlooked this, thanks

Comment: Raven is right - for example if you do not use stockpiles for furniture, they can reuse it immediately. However if dwarf claimed the thing and is going to move it - it is considered used and therefore not available for building.

Comment: Note that if you assign an item to be used in construction (before it's linked to a hauling job) then dwarves won't bother hauling it, even if the construction job isn't active.